# Linear Algebra - Proof solution for a linear system.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this problem :

$Ax=b$ has a solution, lets assume that $u_0$ is a solution for $Ax=b$.

Proof that if $w$ is a solution of $Ax=b$ if and only if exist $u$ that is a solution of $Ax=0$ so $w=u_0+u$.

I'm not sure my proof is correct, I'll be happy to receive feedback.

**My answer :**

**First :**

Lets assume $Aw=b$ is solution and proof that exist $u$ so $Au=0$ so $w=u_0+u$.

We know that $u_0,w$ are solution for $Ax=b$ therefore A is singular since there are two solution for same $b$, Since $A$ singular we can conclude that there is a non-trival solution $u$ so $Au=0$.

Therefore we can conclude that $u_0$ is a solution for non-homogeneous, and $u$ is a solution for homogeneous.

Lets show for $w=u_0+u \implies Aw=b$

$Aw=b \implies A(u_0 + u)=b \implies Au_0+Au = b \implies b+0=b \implies b=b$

Therefore $w$ is a solution.

**Second**

Lets assume that exist $u$ solution for $Ax=0$ and $w=u_0+u$ and proof that $Aw=b$.

$Aw=b \implies A(u_0 + u)=b \implies Au_0+Au = b \implies b+0=b \implies b=b$.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Think of the assumptions and what you are aiming for:

Basic assumption: $\exists u_0$ s.t. $Au_0=b$.

Need to proof:

(1) $Aw=b \implies \exists u$ s.t. $Au=0$ and $w=u_0+u$.
(2) $\forall u$ s.t. $Au=0$, we have $A(u_0+u)=b$.

Comment: @user1537366 Of course I did, I think my proof is valid, however if you think otherwise I'll be glad to get feedback about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. "there is a non-trival solution $u$ so $Au=0$.": Is this $u$ an arbitrary such solution? If so, then we have no guarantees that $w=u_0+u$.
2. You have proven that $Aw=b \implies b=b$. In fact $\text{anything} \implies b=b$. You need to show $b=b \implies Aw=b$.

Comment: 1. Yes, $u$ is arbitrary but I don't understand why there's no guarantee that $w=u_0+u$ in that case, in any case we know that $Au=0$. 

$$$$
About 2, I think I should use $\leftrightarrow$ Instand of $\implies$, What do you think?

Comment: Then as long as there are two distinct solutions for $u$ you cannot just pick any one of them, and in fact any subspace that is bigger than $\{0\}$ has this property. For example, the $u$ picked could be $0$, then obviously that equality $w=u_0+u$ will only hold when $w=u_0$. You need to pick *the* one which makes $w=u_0+u$, like in learnmore's solution. Yes, for part (2) you need to reverse all your $\implies$ signs and check that it is true.

Comment: Two is all clear, but I don't understand one, why I cannot choose any $u$ anyhow it will apply $Au=0$, and I know that $u \neq 0$ since A singluar.

Comment: You are choosing an arbitrary $u$ that satisfies $Au=0$. But you need to show also that there is a $u$ which *both* satisfies $w=u_0+u$ *and* $Au=0$. Yes, you might choose a $u \neq 0$ s.t. $Au=0$ but then $2u$ also will satisfy $A(2u)=0$.

Comment: Yes, but any $u \implies Au=0$ satisfies that $w=u_0+u$ even in case that $u=0 \implies w=u_0$ so $Aw=Au_0=b$

Comment: As well, it unclear using learnmore solution if you choose $w=(w-u_0)+u_0$ how do know that the $w$ we chosen implies Aw=b?

Comment: Try not to use the $\implies$ sign. You are just confusing yourself. In the case $w=u_0$ you indeed need to choose $u=0$, and that works. For the case $w \neq u_0$ you claim that $A$ is singular. This is true. However, then you just chose any non-trivial $u$ that satisfies $Au=0$. Instead, you must chose $u=w-u_0$ so that $w=u_0+u$, and then show that $Au=0$.

Comment: To prove $P \implies Q$ you first start with the assumption that $P$ is *true*. Then try to obtain the conclusion that $Q$ is true. Try not to use the $\implies$ sign in the actual proof unless you are very clear what you mean.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me, I still don't get why I must choose $u=w-u_0$ even if I don't choose that, I still get for any $u$, $Au=0$ and I also get $Aw=b$. while of course $w=u_0+u$

Comment: Please give the exact wording of the question you are proving. I think it is: "Let $A \in \mathcal{M}_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ and $u_0,b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be such that $Au_0=b$. Prove that: $\forall w \in \mathbb{R}^n(Aw=b\quad\text{ if and only if }\quad\exists u \in \mathbb{R}^n\text{ such that }(Au=0\text{ and }w=u_0+u))$."

Comment: Let $Ax=b$ a equation system that has a solution, assume that $u_0$ is a solution for $Ax=b$, Proof that $w$ is a solution of $Ax=b$ if and only if exists $u$ that is a solution for $Ax=0$ so $w=u_0+u$.

Comment: The last "so" is ambiguous. It should be "so that". You should be interpreting the question exactly as in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

Why make the solution so large?Check this.

Hypothesis:$u_0$ is  a solution of $Ax=b$

Assumption: $w$ is a solution of $Ax=b$ Writing $w=(w-u_0)+u_0$ and take $u=(w-u_0)$
Then $A(u)=A(w-u_0)=Aw-Au_0=0$

Conversely,let $w=u_0+u$ where $u $ is a solution of $Ax=0$
Then $Aw=Au_0+Au=b+0=b$.Thus  $w $ satisfies $Ax=b$